# Build UDP datagram in Ruby

Tags: ruby, networking, udp

Is there anything in the Ruby library, or as a Ruby gem, that would help me construct a UDP datagram? I've looked into sockets, but there doesn't seem to be a way to simply build one and not send it.

My use case is this:
I need to build a single UDP datagram, and then pass it off to another module which will be responsible for sending it out. Simply put, I just need to be able to specify the src/dst address and port, as well as the payload.

I suppose in the worse case I can build some kind of a struct and fill in respective bits by hand, but it feels like reinventing the wheel as well as a lot of work. The underlying stuff in the sockets API should have something similar that I can make use of, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The so called socket API is inherently a very low-level C-language API. When you create a UDP socket the connection information is stored in the kernel. You're never "building UDP datagrams", you're writing data into a UDP socket file descriptor, and the physical data packets to be sent over the wire are then constructed inside the kernel.

So yes, if you want a data structure that you can pass around your application that contains a destination address and some data, then you need to create this structure yourself since it doesn't exist by itself anywhere else.

It's not that much work. Just two (or three) data elements. You could use a simple `Struct` to do the job, unless you need more elaborate functionality and then you just build a normal class.

**EDIT**

Looks like I misunderstood your question. See my comment below for resources. For example here's some code from the [Racket library docs](http://spoofed.org/files/racket/doc/), which probably is closer to what you were looking for:

```
 # tack on UDP
 n.l4 = UDP.new
 # randomize source port
 n.l4.src_port = 1024 + rand(65535-1024)
 # take destination port from the commandline
 n.l4.dst_port = ARGV[2].to_i
 # build a random amount of garbage for the payload
 n.l4.payload = Misc.randstring(ARGV[3].to_i)

 # fix 'er  up (checksum, length) prior to sending
 n.l4.fix!(n.l3.src_ip, n.l3.dst_ip)
```

Comment: It's not just simply a data structure that's passed around though, it has to be a proper packet, with all the respective IP and UDP header bits set correctly, including length, checksum, and all that.

Comment: @Calreth Oh ok. I misunderstood what you wanted to do. For that purpose I found a bunch of libraries you might want to look at. They all seem to implement low-level packet classes in one form or another, so you could either extract the code from there or include the best suiting library in your code: http://spoofed.org/files/racket/doc/ | https://github.com/todb/packetfu | http://sylv1.tuxfamily.org/projects/scruby.html | http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/rubypcap/

Comment: Thank you! :) I was able to make use of Racket with success. Only thing it didn't seem to do (at least without using it to actually send the packet) was pad short frames to meet the minimum Ethernet length, but I was able to take care of that easily.